Should I use `overlaySKScene` or `SK3DNode` when mixing SceneKit and SpriteKit?
I am making a 3D game but would like to reuse some of the components in my existing 2D games  (e.g. the pop-up paused window). The top and bottom region where I display menu items are also be 2D. The main canvas is in the center.
There seems to be 2 approaches:

Use SCNView with SCNScene, and set its overlaySKScene for the 2D UI
Use SKView with SKScene, and add a SK3DNode that contains the SCNScene.

The first one is basically putting SpriteKit in SceneKit, and 2nd approach is the opposite. I am wondering which one is the right approach? What's the pros and cons?

I can see one benefit of SK3DNode approach is that I can control the SceneKit's viewport size within the SKScene. However, a regular SceneKit app will take up the whole SCNView so it's not as flexible.

However, with the 2nd approach, I won't have access to SceneKit's SCNSceneRendererDelegate which is part of the SCNView.

I think, the point is, which Scenario dominates in your new app. The 2D SpriteKit or the 3D Scenekit part? As you said, you would like to re-use some of your existing Game-Parts in the new 3D based Game. For my understanding, this new 3D Game would be dominant, just using some of the 2D Stuff. You could probably add some more details, like print screens to your question, that demonstrate the usecases. Things like the Rendering Delegates in SceneKit are quite essential for a SceneKit Game. All in all, my approach would be to Setup a new SceneKit Game from scratch and add the SK stuff as needed.

I did some research on SceneKit's renderer delegate - it looks like I do get update calls from SK3DNode, which can be used for my SceneKit code easily (Though not sure if it's gonna race, because renderer delegate callback happens on background, while SpriteKit's update function happens on main)

it turns out the SceneKit APIs are scoped to main actor contexts anyways (e.g. changing SCNNode position has to be in main actor). So it's actually fine to have SpriteKit to power the update(:) function

I initially went with SK3DNode approach, but encountered 2 limitations:
How to set SCNTechnique for SK3DNode
SK3DNode's hitTest function not finding the right SCNNode
I am not sure if there's a solution to each of them (there could be none). So I had to switch to using SCNView.
